# Javascript promises not resolving in expected order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, couchdb

I've written a function to change the id of couchdb documents I call 'categories' that may include attachments.  This requires several asynchronous operations -- inserting a new document, copying the revision number, copying attachments, deleting the old document, etc -- so I am using promises.

These categories may include subcategories to the nth degree, which have ids that start with the name of the category and are separated by "&&&".  For instance, these are valid id's:

```
"category"
"category&&&subcategory&&&subsubcategory"
```

My problem is, these operations aren't happening in the order I expect.  I've added comments and console logs showing what I expect to see logged.  However, the actual order that is logged, when there are attachments to be copied, is something like the following:

```
1 store.js:365
2 store.js:367
2 store.js:367
2 store.js:367
2 store.js:367
3 store.js:383
4 store.js:385
3 store.js:383
4 store.js:385
3 store.js:383
4 store.js:385
5 store.js:388
5 store.js:388
```

the function:

```
function renameCategory(path, newname){
    var self=this
    return new Promise(function(completed, failed){
        function addAttachment(obj, key, path, newname){
            return new Promise(function(accept, reject){
                var full = `${protocol}://${serverName}/documentation/${path}/${key}`
                self.getFileData(full, true).then(data => {
                    console.log('got the file data')
                    self.saveDoc(key, 'application/pdf', data, newname).then(function(fullurl){
                        accept()
                    })
                })

            })
        }
        function produceCopies(path){
            self.getCategories().then(cats => {
                var result = cats.map(cat => {
                    var rx = new RegExp('^' + path + '(&&&)?')
                    if (rx.test(cat['id'])){
                        return cat['id']
                    }
                }).filter(x => {return x != undefined}).sort((a,b) => {
                    return a.length < b.length
                })
                return Promise.all(result.map(url => {                     //   EACH 'URL' SHOULD BE PROCESSED IN ORDER SO THAT 1, 2, 3, ... SHOULD BE LOGGED IN ORDER...
                    console.log(1)                                         //   STEP 1
                    return self.getData(url).then(data => {
                        console.log(2)                                     //   STEP 2
                        var updatedName = url.replace(path, newname)
                        var obj = Object.assign({}, data)
                        delete obj['_rev']
                        obj._id = updatedName
                        try {
                            delete obj._attachments[url+'.csv']
                        }
                        catch(e){
                        }
                        if (obj['_attachments']){
                            var attachmentKeys = Object.keys(obj['_attachments'])
                            console.log(attachmentKeys + ' are the attachment keys')
                            delete obj._attachments
                            return documentation.insert(obj, updatedName, function(err, body) {
                                if (!err){
                                    console.log(3)                          //  STEP 3
                                    return Promise.all(attachmentKeys.map(key => {
                                        console.log(4)                      //  STEP 4
                                        return addAttachment(obj, key, path, newname).then(function(){
                                            console.log(5)                  //  STEP 5
                                            return self.deleteCategory(url).then(function(){
                                            })
                                        })
                                    }))
                                }
                                else {
                                    failed(err)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('no attachments found')
                            return documentation.insert(obj, updatedName, function(err, body) {
                                if (!err){
                                    return self.deleteCategory(url).then(function(){

                                    })
                                }
                                else {
                                    failed(err)
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })).then(function(){
                    completed()
                })
            })
        }
        produceCopies(path)
    })

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to make these promises resolve in the correct order, so that the console outputs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: Promise.all, will execute each promise in parallel,. But the return value of promise.all will be in order, so maybe use the return value of Promise.all to do your printing etc.  Alternatively, don't use promise all, and do an `async / await` for loop.

Comment: promise.all works in parallel thats why sequence of promise chain could be different from order in which you wrote them in your code.

Comment: Understanding that you are confused by the log sequence but it in fact is acting correctly....are you having any actual problems as a result of it? Note that whatever gets returned to the `then()` in `Promise.all()` will be in the original array order

Comment: Each 1,2,3,4,5 sequence will be in the expected order. Different (sub)sequences may well be interleaved, and this is what you observe the log. Reason being, each sequence has its own asynchonism, the timing of which is not tied to other sequences beyond the `1` stage.